# Grignard Reagent and Ester

Tags: grignard-reagent

Is this answer wrong? [image]I feel like there should be a hydrogen instead of a carbon where I indicated in red. Thank you.

Comment: A possible answer could have been (a) though, especially since they have not specified that the $\ce{MeMgBr}$ here is in excess.

Comment: If e had a hydrogen there it would be the same structure as d.

Comment: Where would the hydrogen come from?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is correct. After the first nucleophilic attack from $\ce{MeMgBr}$, the ethoxy group left and the ester is transformed into a ketone (Step 2 in the link), then another $\ce{MeMgBr}$ attacks and introduce an extra methyl group, resulting in a $3^\circ$ alcohol after hydrolysis. The process is well described in [this page](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Organic_Chemistry/Esters/Reactivity_of_Esters/Grignard_Reagents_Convert_Esters_into_Tertiary_Alcohols).